# Increasing list's size dynamically java

Tags: java, list, collections, size

If I use `list.add(int, int)` method, it will throw an `IndexOutBoundException` if the position is bigger  than or equals to `list.size()`.

I would like to have something that increases the size by adding null elements (if necessairy) until it can safely add a real element to the end.

So lets say I have a `list(list.size()= 0)`, I want to add 5 to the third position, then I would get a list of where the `size` equals to `4`, and the elements are  `null`, `null`, `null`, `5`.

Comment: What do u mean `afely add a real element to the end`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Question makes no sense unless you tell us what your `list` thing actually is.

Comment: Question: why are you trying to make a list into an array?

Comment: Oskar Kjellin comment was useful if you write it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Regenbogenfisch generally comments referring to duplicates should not be posted as answers

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ensureCapacity(int minCapacity)` method of `ArrayList`

Comment: no way. that is completely different

Comment: `ensureCapacity(int)` doesn't change the actual size of the list, it simply allocates memory for a certain size the list can reach before it next needs to copy values. It just saves on incremental reallocation. Moreover, it is an `ArrayList` method, not applicable to any other implementation of `java.util.List`.

Comment: My bad :(. Got confused with the method description: _Increases the capacity of this ArrayList instance, if necessary, to ensure that it can hold at least the number of elements specified by the minimum capacity argument_.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can do this by adding null elements in the List like:


        import java util.List;
        import java.util.ArrayList;

        public class Hello {
         public static void main(String args[]){
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(0, null);
        list.add(1, null);
        list.add(2, null);
        list.add(3, 5);

        System.out.println(list);
        }
        }

Now, you will an output [null, null, null, 5]. I think this might serve your purpose.

Or you can use this way:

List list = Collections.nCopies(5,null);
ArrayList<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
aList.add(5,5);
System.out.println(aList);

You will get an output as : [null, null, null, null, null, 5]

If this could serve your prupose.
```

Comment: Yes, I can do it, but that is what I wanted to avoid and find a more elegant, out-of-box solution if there is any.

Comment: Actually, ArrayList class uses RangeCheck(int index) which private which checks the index with size and returns exception when index>size. So, it won't be possible to add value directly to an index  3 without having values in 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: You can use a loop to add null values before your desired index.

Comment: Maybe I did not express myself clearly enough in the question. I do not really want to do loops, or manual insertions. I know only a limited lists' APIs (Linkedlist, ArrayList etc..), and none of those implementation provide the functionality I need. So I thought maybe there is "FancyUnkownList" out there, that I do not yet know but the community does, with out-of-box functionality.